# Object Oriented Counter

Tags: php

```
<?php 
class Dribble {
  public $shotCount = 0;
  private $shot = false;
  public function shotPosted() {
      $shot = true; 
      if ($shot == true) {
          $shotCount++;
          echo $shotCount;
      }
      if ($shotCount >= 7) {
        exit("You've reached your monthly goal!");
      }
   }
}
$shot1 = new Dribble();
$shot1->shotPosted();
$shot2 = new Dribble();
$shot2->shotPosted();
```

I'm a bit new to object oriented PHP and I'm currently working on a problem that I'm a little stuck on. 
Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `if ($shot = true)` should be `if ($shot == true)`. `=` is assignment, `==` is comparison.

Comment: you need to use `$this->shotCount` for all instances inside of your function

Answer (score 0):

To access a property of the object, you have to use `->` notation in the method. So `$shotCount` should be `$this->shotCount`.

```
class Dribble {
  public $shotCount = 0;
  public function shotPosted() {
      $this->shotCount++;
      echo $this->$shotCount;
      if ($this->$shotCount >= 7) {
        echo "You've reached your monthly goal!";
        $this->shotCount = 0;
      }
   }
}
```

You also shouldn't call `exit()` in the function. The instructions say that `shotCount` should be set back to `0`, but when you exit the script you lose everything.

Answer (score -1):

For this -

```
if ($shot = true) { ... }
```

you probably mean this:

```
if ($shot == true) { ... }
```

= is for assignment, == is to test equality; === tests for equal types as well.

Comment: while this is an error in his code its not the problem or the answer

Comment: He didn't actually say what his problem was, so we were left guessing...